# PHP domdocument modifies my content

Tags: php, domdocument

I am using PHP DOMdocument to remove  tags from my WordPress articles.
    my code is working fine. but when saving back my content,
 it additionally adds

tag for text content. few of the articles got some special chars like Â ,
 I tried load by encoding HTML contents, but still i got the same result. this is how I load my content

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');//dom instant
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);//for setting error false
    $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);//LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD are to remove HTML wrapper
```

it loads my content into html and without html wrapper

Answer (score 0):

The mb_convert_encoding function usually works. Did you set your charset in HTML head to utf-8? On the page from which you're loading:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the replay. i tried that, still i got same result.

Comment: $dom->encoding = 'utf-8'; by using this it removed the special chars, but still it adds <p> tag for text content which is not having any node, any idea how to resolve this